# Remove an element from a LinkedList in O(1)

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list

basically I got the idea of what I'm trying to do in my head cause I usually program in C++ where it is easy to achieve that, not sure how to do that in Java tho.

What I'm trying to do is: keep pointer of Node in LinkedList in java, and removing this specific node in O(1).

If it was C++, I would just do (assuming I'm not trying to remove the last Node)

```
void RemoveNode(Node *node) {
    node->data = node->next->data;
    node->next = node->next->next;
}
```

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: Could you post the Java code you have so far, such as the `Node` class, even if your methods don't yet have any code in them?

Comment: Ofc that I can implement a CustomLinkedList that will do that easily, my question is more like "Is it possible to do that with Java's builtin Lists?".

Answer (score 0):

O(1) removal (besides the obvious removals from head/tail) from a standard `LinkedList` can only be achieved with `ListIterator.remove()`, and you'll have to be iterating through it.

You can't access the internal structure of the list, so all the nodes and their links are inaccessible.